# Error en login con Java

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario login para acceder a una aplicación, pero al igresar las credenciales que están registradas en la base de datos arroja este error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui pongo el código de la función que hace la consulta a la base de datos:

```
public class UsuarioDAO implements CrudPaginadoInterface<Usuario> {

    private final Conexion CON;
    private PreparedStatement ps;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private boolean resp;

    public UsuarioDAO() {
        CON = Conexion.getInstancia();
    }

    public Usuario login(String email, String clave) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            Usuario usu = null;
    
            try {
                ps = CON.conectar().prepareStatement("SELECT u.id, u.id_rol, r.nombre as rol_nombre, u.nombre, u.tipo_documento, "
                        + "u.num_documento, u.direccion, u.telefono, u.email, u.activo "
                        + "FROM usuario u inner join rol r ON u.id_rol = r.id "
                        + "WHERE u.email=? AND clave=?");
                ps.setString(1, email);
                ps.setString(2, clave);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
    
                if (rs.first()) {
                    usu = new Usuario(
                        rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), 
                        rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), 
                        rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), 
                        rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), 
                        rs.getString(9), rs.getBoolean(10)
                    );
                }
    
                ps.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                ps = null;
                rs = null;
                CON.desconectar();
            }
    
            return usu;
        }
```

Desde ya agradecido por las recomendaciones.

Comment: Dónde defines `ps` y `rs`?

Comment: Los defino al inicio de la clase, ahora edité y los coloqué para que se pueda ver mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje indica que tu `ResultSet` obtenido es de tipo `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, indica que el `ResultSet` únicamente puede avanzar entre registros, por lo tanto no puede moverse al primero como lo tratas de realizar:

```
  if (rs.first()) {
       usu = new Usuario(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getBoolean(10));
  }
```

Puedes realizar lo siguiente usando `rs.next()`:

```
while(rs.next())
{
    usu = new Usuario(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getBoolean(10));

 //Agregas cada objeto a un list
}
```

o si necesitas solo el primer resultado como lo estas realizando:

```
if (rs.next()) {
        usu = new Usuario(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getBoolean(10));
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En vez de rs.first()
Usa rs.next()

```java
public class UsuarioDAO implements CrudPaginadoInterface<Usuario> {

    public Usuario login(String email, String clave) {
            Usuario usu = null;

            try (Connection CON = Conexion.getInstancia.conectar();
                 PreparedStatement ps = CON.prepareStatement("SELECT u.id, u.id_rol, r.nombre as rol_nombre, u.nombre, u.tipo_documento, "
                        + "u.num_documento, u.direccion, u.telefono, u.email, u.activo "
                        + "FROM usuario u inner join rol r ON u.id_rol = r.id "
                        + "WHERE u.email=? AND clave=?")) {
                
                ps.setString(1, email);
                ps.setString(2, clave);
                try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                   if (rs.next()) {
                     
                      usu = new Usuario(
                        rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), 
                        rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), 
                        rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), 
                        rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), 
                        rs.getString(9), rs.getBoolean(10)
                    );
              

                   // revisar si me haquearon
                   if (rs.next()) {
                      // alerta:hack
                      log.warn("Intento de hack...");
                      return null;
                   }

                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            } 
    
            return usu;
        }
    }
}
```

Me tome la libertad de modernizar el codigo y limpiar varios errores como mantener abierta la conexion y no hacer los close() en lugares seguros (con el nuevo try with resources se maneja automagicamente)